# javascript element.style.left Not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Setting element top,left via javascript stops working,Perviously it was working perfectly.

```
ifrmObj.style.left = 100;
ifrmObj.style.top = 150;
```

Now i have to add a 'px' with number. What is the change that i made is the reason for this issue

Comment: Try `ifrmObj.style.left = 100 + 'px';`

Comment: But without px its worked for me.

Comment: Remove <!DOCTYPE HTML> from your file and it will work fine.
The "px" is required by the html standards. So when you tell your browser it is reading html, it follows a strict set of rules. 
Those rules can be ignored if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Do not forget to suffix the number with 'px'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use position first then left or top will work like,

Syntax:

```
object.style.position="static|absolute|fixed|relative|initial|inherit"
```

For egs,

```
ifrmObj.style.position='absolute';//relative or fixed
```

To add px in your numbers,

For static numbers

```
ifrmObj.style.left = '100px';
ifrmObj.style.top = '150px';
```

For variables numbers

```
var x=100,y=150;
ifrmObj.style.left = x+'px';
ifrmObj.style.top = y+'px';
```

And if you are using jquery then use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) in one go like,

```
$(ifrmObj).css({'left':'100px','top':'150px','position':'absolute'});
```

Comment: Previously without adding px, its worked for me. Now its stops working. Need to find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this issue that was not addressed. Remove the following from the top of your html file that is using the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what that reason.. and you can add to CSS code a class for ex:

#### HTML Code

```
<div id="div"> <p> abcd </p></div>
```

#### CSS Code

```
.edit-left {left: 0 ;}
```

#### JS

```
const handleClickProjects = () => {
     console.log("click")
        let element= document.getElementById("div");
        if (element.classList.contains("edit-left")) {
            element.classList.remove("edit-left")  
        }
        else {
            element.classList.add("edit-left")
        }
    }
```

This for ReactJS. For pure JS use addEventListener....
(this code has a default left arg)